# Use a fallback font in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, fonts, tkinter

I'm setting up a simple program with Tkinter and am trying to use a custom font. I create the font using

```
myFont = tkinter.font.Font(family='<familyName>')
```

I want to use a fallback font if familyName isn't available on the user's computer. However, Tkinter doesn't raise an error or give any feedback if familyName isn't available and instead just uses the default font.

How do I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tinter.font.families()` returns a tuple of available families so you can check availability before calling Font.  Note that one must not only import `tkinter.font` first, but as of 3.4.3, at least, create a root window before calling either `Font` or `families`.

The official tkinter doc has no section on tkinter.font.  Two other useful utilities are `names()` (of defined fonts) and `nametofont(name)`.